# How to convert a dict of lists to a list of tuples of key and value in python?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, dictionary

I have a dict of lists like this:

```
y = {'a':[1,2,3], 'b':[4,5], 'c':[6]}
```

I want to convert the dict into a list of tuples, each element of which is a tuple containing one key of the dict and one element in the value list:

```
x = [
    ('a',1),('a',2),('a',3),
    ('b',4),('b',5),
    ('c',6)
    ]
```

My code is like this:

```
x = reduce(lambda p,q:p+q, map(lambda (u,v):[(u,t) for t in v], y.iteritems()))
```

Such a code seems hard to read, so I wonder if there is any pythonic way, or more precisely, a way in list comprehension to do such thing?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could do something like this,

```
>>> y = {'a':[1,2,3], 'b':[4,5], 'c':[6]}
>>> [(i,x) for i in y for x in y[i]]
[('a', 1), ('a', 2), ('a', 3), ('c', 6), ('b', 4), ('b', 5)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach, but not necessarily more readable or pythonic:

```
>>> from itertools import izip_longest
>>> y = {'a':[1,2,3], 'b':[4,5], 'c':[6]}
>>> [tuple(izip_longest(k, v, fillvalue=k)) for k, v in y.items()]
[(('a', 1), ('a', 2), ('a', 3)), (('c', 6),), (('b', 4), ('b', 5))]
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed to get a list of key-value pair to then submit it to `itertools.product`
In my case, having a nested list for each key was preferable. So, I used the solution below, which gives a result similar to that of BioGeek but is pure list comprehension:

```
foo = {'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [4, 5],"c":[6]}
bar = [[(x,z) for z in y] for x,y in foo.items()]
print(bar)
>> [[('a', 1), ('a', 2), ('a', 3)], [('b', 4), ('b', 5)], [('c', 6)]]
```