# Converting dictionary with multiple strings into 2D Array/List

Tags: python, arrays, list, dictionary, multivalue

Similar questions:

[How to convert a dict of lists to a list of tuples of key and value in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28807508/how-to-convert-a-dict-of-lists-to-a-list-of-tuples-of-key-and-value-in-python?rq=3)

[Python convert dictionary where keys have multiple values into list of tuples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55695217/python-convert-dictionary-where-keys-have-multiple-values-into-list-of-tuples)

My question is very similar to the above links, however the answers there do not work for me because instead of 1 letter values, I have worded strings - e.g.

`{"My": "[dog, cat, bird]", "is":"[cute]", "Hi":[], "Hello":"[World]"}`

I want this to be like:

`[('My'),('dog')],[('My), ('cat')], [('My'),('bird')], [('is'), ('cute')], [('Hello', ('World')]`

The solutions to the above links does not work because it iterates through every letter in the value, whereas I want the entire word. I have tried using split() to split each value by a comma and then allocate it a value in a new array however I'm having complications with that as I am not familiar with dictionaries in python so unable to come up with a working solution.

Comment: "The solutions to the above links does not work because it iterates through every letter in the value" no those solutions don't do that. If you claim that is happening, you **must** provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think nested loop inside list comprehension still works even with worded strings as python sees single letter value also as a string

```
data = {"My": ["dog", "cat", "bird"], "is":["cute"], "Hi":[], "Hello":["World"]} 

lst = [(k, v) for k in data for v in data[k]]
```

Update:
If the dictionary value is a string instead of a list, you can do some string manipulation to remove the brackets (`data[k][1:-1]`) and split the string by commas so that it can be iterated as a list (`.split(", ")`)

```
lst = [(k, v) for k in data if not isinstance(data[k], list) for v in data[k][1:-1].split(", ")]
```

Comment: That doesn't work because it iterates through every letter inside the values i.e. creating `[('My'),('d')],[('My), ('o')], [('My'),('g')]`. I need it to be `[(My), (dog)]`

Comment: @hi_it'sme no it doesn't. That code produces the output you wanted. You obviously haven't provided a [mcve]

Comment: Uh I don't  think it will iterate through every letter because the first for loop iterates through the dictionary key `("My", "is", "Hello")` and the second for loop iterates through each item of the list corresponding to the key of dicitionary `(["dog", "cat", "bird"], ["cute"], [], ["World"])` . You can run the code I shared above and run `print(lst)` to confirm

Comment: I have run print(lst) on the code and I am getting [('My'),('d'),('My), ('o'), ('My'),('g')]. Not sure why that's happening but that is the output.

Comment: Apologies, i think I've realised the problem. My dictionary doesnt have multiple values, it is just words separated by commas. I have updated my question accordingly.

Comment: @hi_it'sme Oh I see, yep I've updated my answer for case where the dictionary value is a raw string instead of list of strings